# sql - syntax of self-joined table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of categories, which could me in 2 levels: a parent category and a sub-category, where if the parent-category is 0 - then its a parent cat, and otherwise, its a sub-category. Any sub with have a parent, but some parents may not have subs yet.

```
   categoryID   |  categoryName    |   parentID
---------------------------------------------------
       1        |    cat 1         |        0         (parent cat)
       2        |    cat 2         |        1         (sub of #1)
```

I would like a table, that lists:
`categoryID, categoryName, ParentCategoryID, parentCategoryName`

If i do an INNER JOIN, then I lose out on parent cats that do not have subs.
Example:

```
SELECT 
    Sub.[categoryName] As SubcatName, Sub.categoryID, 
    Parent.[categoryName] As ParentCatName, Sub.[parentID] AS parentID 
FROM 
    [tblCategories] Parent INNER JOIN [tblCategories] Sub 
ON 
     Sub.[parentID] = Parent.[categoryID]
```

If i do a LEFT OUTER JOIN (Parent --> Sub) then I get subcategories coming up as a parent.

If i do a LEFT OUTER JOIN (parent --> Sub) - then i again only get those categories that have parent cats.

Can someone suggest a query syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT cat2.[categoryId]
  ,cat2.[categoryName]
  ,cat2.[parentid]
  ,cat1.categoryName
 FROM [category] cat1
 RIGHT JOIN [category] cat2
     on cat2.parentid = cat1.categoryId
```

[original entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztxkE.png)

Answer (score 2):

using a recursive cte:

```
;with cte as (
-- anchor elements: where parentId = 0
  select 
      categoryId
    , categoryName
    , parentId
    , parentName = convert(varchar(32),null)
  from t
  where parentId = 0
  -- recursion begins here
  union all 
  select 
      c.categoryId 
    , c.categoryName
    , c.parentId
    , parentName = p.categoryName
  from t c
    inner join cte as p on c.parentId= p.categoryId
)
-- we select all the results 
select *
from cte
```